# Scope of a Type Name in Protocols

Tags: swift

I find myself hitting name space conflicts in type declarations.  Like:

```
protocol Identifier : Hashable {}

// Something is Identifiable if it has an Identifier
protocol Identifiable : Hashable {
  typealias Identifier : Identifier  // error: doesn't 'see' 'protocol Identifier'
  var identifier : Identifier { get }
}
```

The simple solution is to define `protocol IdentifierType : Hashable {}` but that doesn't read right to me.  Or in `Identifiable` to use `typealias IdentifierType : Identifier` but then all types satisfying `Identifiable` specialize on `IdentiferType` and that doesn't read right to me.

Another case:

```
protocol Food {}
class FoodService <Food : Food> {}  // error
```

So what is the naming convention that I should be using? Am I just formulating the relationship between two types incorrectly?  Is there a way to express `typealias Identifier : Global.Identifier`?

Edit: Responding to a Comment -- If instead I avoid the `typealias` completely and tried:

```
protocol Identifiable : Hashable {
  var identifier : Identifier { get }
}
```

then I get a compiler error of "Protocol Identifier can only be used as a generic constraint ..."

Comment: Hmm, why do you need to typealias this exactly?

Comment: You mean in `Identifiable` remove the `typealias` and use `var identifier : Hashable { get }`?  I've simplified the protocols to illustrate the issue; the actual problem has more to it.  But, I"m interested in your thoughts.

Comment: No.  I mean why not use `var identifier: Identifier`.  The `Identifier` protocol is already declared outside the `Identifiable` protocol.  Is it that crucial to typealias it within the `Identifiable` protocol?

Comment: Edited to reflect your suggest attempt - leads to a 'can only be used as a generic constrain ...' error.  Also, I think I need the the Identifiable typealias as implementations of that protocol will subtype based on the Identifier - String, Int, others.